# Hafele–Keating experiment

Tags: general-relativity, special-relativity

So what times would be shown on the various clocks if the Hafele–Keating experiment was done North-South rather than West-East?

Which clock(s) would be slower and why?

There will be the same relative velocities as before but North-South would make them a symmetrical pair rather than asymmetrical (for and against rotation).

Comment: Note that at least one reason for going both East and West in the experiment is because there are different expectations for the results in those directions and that helps you disentangle the effects that are attributable to pure special relativistic effects from those related to general relativity.

Comment: But if North-South is used then although there is relative motion between the moving clocks you are then saying that their results are identical? This would be against Relativity in general as any relative motion should produce time changes. The ground based clocks should be 'faster' than the moving clocks as previously. But the moving clocks would be equally 'slower' as regards them but they cannot be identical as there has been some relative velocity between them.

Comment: You would need to account for the Coriolis effect in the calculations, but yes, I would expect the clocks on North-bound and South-bound flights to show identical time-dilation.